# Kendo Chart plot lines

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a Kendo UI scatter plot representing trade volumes over a time series.  The chart works well, but now I need to add a vertical plot line on the x-axis (time) at a specific time, representing a price-fluctuation point.  Is it possible to draw such lines at a specific x-axis value, along with a label or tooltip explaining the data details?  I see plot bands, but that seems not useful here.

Thanks in advance for any hints/suggestions.
I *could* add a new line series with points at (time, 0) and (time, y), but I would like to see if there is a better/API way before I go that route.

Comment: You can use the render event and the drawing API. Here is an example for a Horizontal line: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/custom-plot-bands#in-bar-charts  You can adapt this to the axis types you are using...

Comment: Thanks!  I think that will work for now. I appreciate the link as well.